# Multiple Jquery-ui dilaog box with one button

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery ui Dialog box. It works fine but I have a requirement that with one button I should be able to create a dialog box with each click.

So Eg: On first click a dialog box is opened. On second click, a new dialog must be created with the first one intact at it's place. I am implementing sticky notes using this.

How can this be achieved??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Modal Dialog Dynamically

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var dynamicDialog = $('<div id="MyDialog">cotent            </div>');
    dynamicDialog.dialog({
        title: "Success Message",
        modal: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Yes",
            click: function () {}
        }]
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7van44b3/)

Note: since all come on same location just move and see the new dialog in the demo

Comment: Can the positioning be done such that each comes at a different location??

Comment: You can use the `position`

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: hope you will vote the answer when you have time :)

Comment: With position for every new dialog, it will be dynamic. How to handle that?

Comment: I wanted to open a dialog (pop-up) which will be full width of the window and inside that pop-up give this functionality of creating sticky notes as above. How can the big dialog which opens full width be created? Any idea?